# Extract a series of reference numbers from a string

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a field in a database which contains user comments.

These comments sometimes contain order reference numbers, delivery reference numbers or carrier references. Order References follow the format

- X##########
- Delivery Refs: TR######
- Carrier Refs: FC#####

These references are surrounded by other information in the user's comments, so appear sporadically with no fixed pattern.

Example Data: "Item lost due to order duplication X1234567890 possibly also due to theft"

What I wish to do is create 3 extra columns in my table, one for each of these references, then search the user comments and extract these references to their rightful column.

This will be executed within Access but would be also needed in excel.

Can anyone help with a Visual Basic function to do this?

Please Help! I've been pulling my hair out!

Comment: This will be used to calculate over 150,000 records...

Comment: Regular Expressions might be useful, depending on your data.

Comment: I have spent quite a few hours trying to work this out with regular expressions but can't find a way. The closes I got was using the SEARCH function in excel to find the starting position of the reference but need the ?
 wildcard to only recognise numbers which unfortunately it doesn't. And so it doesnt work if there is an X anywhere before the reference.

Comment: It's really hard to help you with your function when you forgot to include the function in the question.  Please paste it in, and tell us which bit isn't working correctly, and then we will happily help you get it working.

Comment: This sounds fairly trivial - but you would need to give at least some example of the data you are working with. For example are the various "References" fixed length strings? What format (zero padded, numbers, letters, uppercase, etc) are the ####. If you can provide some more info I am sure loads of people will be able to help you out.

Comment: I don't have a function yet unfortunately. Thats what I need help with :D

Comment: Please read [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and **especially** [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so you can provide us with enough information to help you.

Comment: If you don't have an exisiting function, how did you try to use regular expressions?

Comment: I have tried this =MID(A1,SEARCH("X??????????",A1),11) in excel. It works great until an X appears prior to the reference.

Comment: You should open another question asking how to identify the 3 patterns using regular expressions and post your code with that.  Once you get that working update this question and ask how to apply the new code sample to this question

Comment: That has nothing to do with regular expressions.

Comment: Example Data: "Item lost due to order duplication X1234567890 possibly also due to theft"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use Regular Expressions.

Following function returns VBA.Collection of pairs. First item of pair contains type of number (X or TR or FC) and second item contains the number.

```
Public Function ParseComment(comment As String) As VBA.Collection

    Set ParseComment = New VBA.Collection

    Static RegExp As Object
    If RegExp Is Nothing Then
        Set RegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
            RegExp.IgnoreCase = True
            RegExp.Pattern = "\b(X|TR|FC)(\d+)\b"
            RegExp.Global = True
    End If

    Dim match As Object
    For Each match In RegExp.Execute(comment)
        ParseComment.Add Array(match.SubMatches(0), match.SubMatches(1))
    Next match

End Function
```